# installing DBpedia spotlight on windows 7

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish-4, spotlight-dbpedia

I'm using [DBpedia spotlight web service](http://dbpedia-spotlight.github.io/demo/) on my project and it suddenly stop working, it does not annotate even the default text on it.

I've searched the internet and it seems that I have to install the server on my laptop. But I don't understand [those instructions](https://github.com/dbpedia-spotlight/dbpedia-spotlight/wiki/Run-from-a-JAR).

I'm using the statistical version:

1. I downloaded the `en.tar.gz` file as mentioned
2. I downloaded `dbpedia-spotlight.jar` as mentioned

Now what?

My project is built using Netbeans and Glassfish server, and I have win7 as OS.

Any help? And is there any memory requirement for that?

Answer (score 0):

Stack Overflow is focused on programming questions. This doesn't appear to be a programming question.

DBpedia Spotlight has [its own mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/mailman/listinfo/dbp-spotlight-users) among other [support areas](https://github.com/dbpedia-spotlight/dbpedia-spotlight/wiki/Support-and-Feedback), and you're likely to get better and faster answers there from the experts in the space, than from random folks here.